# 16.04 GUI crashes with mouse use

Tags: 16.04, mouse, gui

I'm a new Ubuntu/Linux user.

I have an UDOO x86 Board, and I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 onto the emmc. I can do keyboard commands, but when I plug in a mouse the window/gui will go away after a graphical glitch and then the screen turns orange.

No key command will bring it back. I've turned off the monitor a few times with no luck. AFTER a reboot it goes back to normal. It signed me into a guest account. I got around that with some keyboard witchery. I tried to enable mouse with keyboard controls; it didn't make the mouse cursor move, BUT it did cause the same graphical glitch and no GUI.

Is there some way I can install a driver from a USB stick via non GUI terminal?

I've tried 3 different mice and they all do the same thing. Now on the sign in screen i cant go more than 4 seconds before the graphical problem happens and it becomes useless again. I found [this article](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2) but apparently I can't update without my GUI.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go on fixing the problem *without* a GUI, but only on the command line, then you can press CTRL-ALT-F1, which will bring you to a text-only console. There you can log in and you should be able to install the intel tools from the URL you've posted.

You should be able to update from the command line with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

To change back to the GUI press ALT-Fx in the console - one of the function keys will bring you back to the GUI.

Of interest to you should be files in `/var/log`. List them sorted by time (aka `ls -latr /var/log` and you should be able to see which ones have changed recently - those would be of interest to you). Of particular interest for you would be:

- `kern.log` - contains kernel messages. If the kernel has bad problems with something (here: your USB bus), then it should say so in this log file
- `Xorg.0.log` - messages from the GUI. If the graphical subsystem has any problems with the hardware then it should tell you there

You should be able to look at those files with the `less` command - thus: `less /var/log/kern.log`. You'd quit with `q` and page forward and back with the `page down`, `page up` keys.

Comment: look i have the driver i want to use in my usb drive, i just dont know the commands to get it out and install the thing. i dont understand linux terminology at all, but it would be easier with a gui. I cant use the gui BECAUSE the problem exists. how do i install the update with the url?

Comment: You log in from the console. You either need to log in as root or become root with `sudo su`. Then you stick the drive in. Then you issue `dmesg` on the command line. At the end the kernel will tell you under which name it's seeing the drive. Alternatively you can also issue `lsblk`. Then you mount the stick with `mount /dev/sdXX /mnt` where sdXX is the name you've found with one of the previous two commands.  Install the package with `dpkg -i /mnt/packageXXXXXXXX.deb`. Unmount: `umount /mnt`. `reboot`.